# Restangular error while requesting OAUTH token

Tags: angularjs, cordova, oauth, restangular

I'm building a mobile app using AppGyver and AngularJS.

At the login page, I do a POST request to my Web API server using this:

```
Restangular.all("token")
.post({
    grant_type: "password",
    username:username,
    password:password
});
```

My RESTangular is set-up this way:

```
appServerModule.config(function(RestangularProvider) {

    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://192.168.1.58/AppServer/api');

    RestangularProvider.setErrorInterceptor(function(response) {

        steroids.logger.log("RestangularProvider error:" + JSON.stringify(response));
    });
});
```

When I execute the POST request I get the following output in my logger:

```
"RestangularProvider error:{"data":"","status":0,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"},"url":"http://192.168.1.58/AppServer/api/token","data":{"grant_type":"password","username":"AppServer","password":"AppServer"}},"statusText":""}"
```

As you can see, the error message doesn't contain any useful information, so I don't know what is going wrong..
I can execute the POST just fine using Postman in the browser and the Web API is set up to allow CORS.

What am I missing here?
How can I get more information about what is happening behind the scenes?

Please note that I'm doing this on a mobile device.

Extra info:
A GET request provides this expected Restangular error:

```
"RestangularProvider error:{"data":{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."},"status":401,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"url":"http://192.168.1.58/AppServer/api/chapters"},"statusText":"Unauthorized"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

OWIN OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server does not support JSON for the token request.

You need to use x-www-form-urlencoded instead of JSON while making the request from the javascript client:

```
Restangular.all("token")
.post("grant_type=password&username=YourUsername&password=YourPassword", undefined, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
});
```